# PHP loop echoing blank return

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm doing some backend Wordpress development and want to associate a guid permalink with a certain value referenced by the variable `$post_number`.

The goal is to echo an array of guid links to be handled with JavaScript/jQuery on the page.  The problem is that currently I'm getting nothing for the value, indicating that something is up with the loop logic, but I can't seem to determine what the issue is.

```
<?php 
    $stmt2 = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM wp_posts');
    $i = 1;
    //Variable $post_number is post_id from wp_postmeta.  The idea is to compare it to the post ID in the wp_posts database so I can get the post GUID
    while ($row = $stmt2->fetch()) {
        foreach ($post_number as $value){
            //Grab the guid for the post ID
            if($row['ID'] == $value[$i]) {        
                //get guid of the post and store in string
                $post_guid[] = $row['guid'];
            }
            else{}
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='cover_post_guids' value='".json_encode($post_guid)."'>";
?>
```

Comment: What value does $post_number have?

Comment: What is $post_numbers ?

Comment: In this loop I'm checking if the Row ID equals the post_id from the postmeta table, so $post_number is an array (filled out earlier) that contains the wp-postmeta post_ID numbers that I check against the ID numbers of the wp_post table, getting the guid value of rows that match.

Comment: What is $post_number you are doing your code in that loop only.

Comment: I see a foreach nested in a while.  That might be necessary, but it could be an indication of something that needs to be rethought.  You're also using a counter (`$i = $i + 1`) with a foreach.  That also waves a flag.  I question whether `$value[$i]` is what you think it is.  Without seeing `print_r($post_number)` though, we have no way of knowing if your code is accessing what you think it's accessing.